# unable to tokenize file data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am new to hadoop and mapreduce. In mapper i am going to tokenize these data from the text file with below given format with first few lines

```
9593C58F7C1C5CE4    970916072134    levis
9593C58F7C1C5CE4    970916072311    levis strause & co
9593C58F7C1C5CE4    970916072339    levis 501 jeans
45531846E8E7C127    970916065859    
45531846E8E7C127    970916065935    
45531846E8E7C127    970916070105    "brazillian soccer teams"
45531846E8E7C127    970916070248    "brazillian soccer"
45531846E8E7C127    970916071154    "population of maldives"
082A665972806A62    970916123431    pegasus
F6C8FFEAA26F1778    970916070130    "alicia silverstone" cutest crush batgirl babysitter clueless 
945FF0D5996FD556    970916142859    mirc
```

With String Tokenizer I am unable to split these data, its confuses to the machine to catching data from this file.Is there any alternative for this problem except String.split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Hanry : Why don't you use the same java **StringTokenizer**. All you have to do is to tokenize wrt space, get the total token count and then iterate through and use First and Second tokens as such and concatenate subsequent tokens into a third string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextInputFormat to be given each line at a time, then if it truly is fixed width format and you have a constant number of fields (3) then you can do something like:

```
Text token1 = new Text();
Text token2 = new Text();
Text token3 = new Text();

protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
    // 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
    //           1         2         3
    // 9593C58F7C1C5CE4    970916072134    levis

    if (value.getLength() >= 37) {
      token1.set(value.getBytes(), 0, 16);
      token2.set(value.getBytes(), 20, 12);
      token3.set(value.getBytes(), 26, value.getLength() - 26);

      // TOFO: Do something with these tokens
    } else {
      // TODO: handle bad record length
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**: Totally untested